# C++ can't solve my problem. I have console error

Tags: c++

I dont know C++ but I need help, solution. I want to read from file words.txt strings and if separator ',' comes then program should cut off this line and go further to the next one. Its working 50/50 because I have error in console:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::lenght_error'
what(): basic_string::_M_replace_aux
```

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void print( string::size_type n, string const & s )
{
    if( n == string::npos ) {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    } else {
        cout << "found: " << s.substr( n ) << '\n';
    }
}


int main()
{
    map < char, int > pythagorean;

    pythagorean[ 'a' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'b' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 'c' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'd' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'e' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'f' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'g' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'h' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'i' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 'j' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 'k' ] = 9;
    pythagorean[ 'l' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'm' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'n' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'o' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'p' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'q' ] = 6;
    pythagorean[ 'r' ] = 7;
    pythagorean[ 's' ] = 8;
    pythagorean[ 't' ] = 9;
    pythagorean[ 'u' ] = 1;
    pythagorean[ 'v' ] = 2;
    pythagorean[ 'w' ] = 3;
    pythagorean[ 'x' ] = 4;
    pythagorean[ 'y' ] = 5;
    pythagorean[ 'z' ] = 6;


    string::size_type n;
    ifstream input( "words.txt" );
    ofstream output( "Results.txt" );
    string str;
    int counter = 0, cnt = 0;


    while( getline( input, str ) )
    {
        int sum = 0;

        n = str.find( ',' );
        str.resize( n );

        for( char charr: str )
        {
            sum += pythagorean[ charr ];
        }

        if( sum == 11 )
        {
            cout << str << "(" << sum << ")" << '\n' << "Pythagorean: " << '\t';
            output << "Pythagorean: " << '\t' << str << " = " << sum << endl;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\n You have found: " << counter << " words" << '\n';
    output << "\n\n You have found: " << counter << " words" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone give me a solution? Im really bad in C++ and I need it to check a lot of datas in .txt file. Please:)

Comment: Unrelated: `#include <stdio.h>` seems to have been added for no reason at all. 1) It's a C header file. The C++ version is `<cstdio>`. 2) You don't use anything defined in that file so remove it.

Comment: I know basics. Can someone help me?

Comment: Not your current problem, haven't found it yet, but In `n = str.find( ',' ); str.resize( n );`, if no comma is found, `n` will be `npos`, and `npos` is a very, **very** large number. Almost certainly larger than the available amount of memory.

Comment: Well well well. That is the bug. Didn't know `resize` threw `std::length_error`.

Comment: So what should I do? If no comma is found then what program should do? You found solution right? ```resize``` threw this error?

Comment: Writing an answer. have it up once I've crossed the 't's and dotted the 'i's.

Comment: Come to think of it, All I can recommend is how to avoid the error. I do not know if it is the correct thing to do in your circumstances.

Comment: Alright but resize caused this error? Because n became a very large number?

Comment: Yes, [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) may return `npos`, so you must check for this.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
n = str.find( ',' );
str.resize( n );
```

if there is no comma in `str`, [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) will return `npos` and `npos` is an incredibly large number that a `std::string` cannot be resized to fit.  This is precisely why `npos` is used to signal no match found: `npos` cannot possibly be a valid index in the string.

To avoid the problem test   `n` against `npos`

```
n = str.find( ',' );
if (n != std::string::npos)
{ // found a comma
    str.resize( n );
}
else
{ // did not find a comma
    // Handle the error as best fits the needs of the program.
    // Perhaps this is not an error and the program can continue parsing with 
    // the whole string.
    // But if there must be a comma and one cannot be found, there is a protocol
    // error in the file and the user should be notified before continuing or 
    // halting the program.
}
```

Comment: It solved problem with console error. Thanks but my program still doesnt work properly.
I mean my file ```words.txt``` looks like this
```ace,asdasdas```
```bull,asdsads```
```kupa```
```psalm,asdasdas```

Ace
Bull
Psalm

All of them have value of 11 but my program showing me only two words, Bull and Ace, there is no Psalm

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what the program is supposed to do or the how the input file is supposed to be structured, so all I can offer is how to avoid the current problem. It is possible that what you need to do is `while( getline( input, str , ',') )` to seek all contents between commas regardless of line endings. Without more information, the answer is doomed to be incomplete. This should get you on a better path, though.

Comment: Ok nevermind, psalm was not 11. It works perfect. Thank you

Comment: Step through the program with whatever debugger came with your development tools and see what your program is really doing. Where it differs from your expected, you have a bug. Or your expectations are wrong. Either way it's a problem that needs fixin.

Comment: How i can give you a reputation point? You helped me. Problem is solved:)

Comment: Some time in the near future, I don't know how far in the future, you will be able to mark the question as answered with a green (well, people tell me it's green) checkmark. Check again later to see if the option has become available. Also keep an eye out for someone leaving a better answer and select it instead.

Comment: Nevermind. I wish you all the best and once more, thank you for help:)